# Convert a list of string sentences to words

Tags: python, string, sentence

I'm trying to essentially take a list of strings containg sentences such as:

```
sentence = ['Here is an example of what I am working with', 'But I need to change the format', 'to something more useable']
```

and convert it into the following:

```
word_list = ['Here', 'is', 'an', 'example', 'of', 'what', 'I', 'am',
'working', 'with', 'But', 'I', 'need', 'to', 'change', 'the format',
'to', 'something', 'more', 'useable']
```

I tried using this:

```
for item in sentence:
    for word in item:
        word_list.append(word)
```

I thought it would take each string and append each item of that string to word_list, however the output is something along the lines of:

> ```
> word_list = ['H', 'e', 'r', 'e', ' ', 'i', 's' .....etc]
> ```

I know I am making a stupid mistake but I can't figure out why, can anyone help?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need `str.split()` to split each string into words:

```
word_list = [word for line in sentence for word in line.split()]
```

Comment: Thanks again, I knew I was missing something easy like that, much appreciated!

Comment: This should be `[word for line in sentence for word in line.split()]`.

Comment: Upvoted, though keep in mine more than 2 clauses of iteration is generally frowned upon in list comprehensions.

Comment: I know this has been sometime but can I get explanation on the code? I understand `[line for line in sentence]` but I dont understand the second half `for word in line.split()`. How is it different from `[line.split() for line in sentence]` ?

Comment: One important syntax to learn here is in single list notation with multiple for loops, thanks ..

Answer (score 7):

Just `.split` and `.join`:

```
word_list = ' '.join(sentence).split(' ')
```

Answer (score 4):

You haven't told it how to distinguish a word. By default, iterating through a string simply iterates through the characters.

You can use `.split(' ')` to split a string by spaces. So this would work:

```
for item in sentence:
    for word in item.split(' '):
        word_list.append(word)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for item in sentence:
    for word in item.split():
        word_list.append(word)
```

Answer (score -1):

Split sentence into words:

```
print(sentence.rsplit())
```